# Como puedo crear una Barra de tabs con ionic y supertabs

Tags: ionic

Quisiera hacer algo similar a esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En este caso quiero usar la libreria de `@ionic-super-tabs/angular`, que podira hacer para este caso?

Comment: Ya existe una pregunta, puedes consultarlo aquí; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60578210/ionic-4-tabs-how-to-create-custom-tabs

Comment: Hola, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Codigo o Ejemplo Minimo Reproducible, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], He visto que has agregado Imágenes, es preferible que tus ejemplos sean en texto y facilites el uso del mismo, También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].